# Who brought Captain Archer to the 31st century?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

In a short sentence in the end of ["Shockwave. Part I" episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shockwave_(episode)), Agent Daniels says two things:

> 1. That he was ordered to bring Archer to 31st century. 2. That he was eating a breakfast just a half an hour ago.

These two pieces of information seem to contradict each other. Who gave order and who actually performed it -- i.e. brought Captain Archer to the 31st century?

Comment: What about those two statements is contradictory? Daniels isn't allowed to have breakfast?

Comment: Also you've asked five similar questions about this episode in rapid succession. Did you perform research on any of them or consider asking one then waiting for a while?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have some question about the phrase "earing a breakfast" that sounds gross.

Comment: It seems that after I spent a couple of years here, I am getting old and I must be missing the key idea of opinion-based questions. This is another VTC question of mine where the completely not opinion-based answer would be "This issue is not explained in the episode". Amen. To coop with your questions. (a) Yes, I did a research and found nothing. If I slip an obvious answer in an easy-to-find source then please, correct me by pointing it.

Comment: (b) A number of questions asked in a row and the fact that all asks about the same episode shouldn't be an issue here -- I was always taught that we should formulate single question per single thing to ask and not to accumulate more than one question, even about the same episode in a single SE entity. Finally, (c) for me there's a clear contradiction: Having a breakfast (while pointing a kitchen when you're saying this) clearly means that you're at home. Daniels most likely was not performing his duties at home and cloudn't operate time device while eating scrammbled egg, am I correct?

Comment: @trejder:   What's the problem?   They have communicators and transporters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no contradiction: half an hour ago he was having breakfast, then he started his work day by bringing Archer to the 31st century, resulting in a massive alteration of the timeline.

The order was given by whatever superior officer in the 31st century StarFleet/Federation give those orders, the hierarchy of Daniel's agency is never explained on screen, and Daniels followed the order as he always does.

> [Devastated building]
>
> (Archer steps through the tangled mass of girders until he comes to a broken window, and looks out on a cityscape of wrecked skyscrapers and a sullen grey cloudy sky.)
>
> DANIELS: Ten minutes ago, that vista was more beautiful than anything you could imagine.
>
> ARCHER: Where am I?
>
> DANIELS: I had breakfast in that room less than half an hour ago. Then I was instructed to bring you here. They told me that the timeline wouldn't be safe if you boarded that Suliban ship. Someone was very mistaken.
>
> ARCHER: Where is here?
>
> DANIELS: You're in the thirty first century, Captain, or what's left of it.